# DotNetOpenAuth - How to generate a multi-part request with some query string parameters?

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, multipart

I need to make oAuth  multipart request message for the API which requires some query string parameters as well as Multipart Post Part.
But there is no PrepareAuthorizedRequest Method which accepts both IDictionary type query string parameters and MultipartPostPart fields.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a `MessageReceivingEndpoint` whose URI already includes those query string parameters.